# res/baseResource.plist is not a plist file or you forgot to preload the plist file

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-html5

I am trying out the samples that come with
Cocos2d-html-v2.2.2

The frameworks seems to run fine, but there is a problem with theincluded games.

FruitAttack gives me the following error on the Developer Console

```
Uncaught cocos2d: res/baseResource.plist is not a plist file or you forgot to preload the plist file CCSAXParser.js:62
cc.SAXParser.cc.Class.extend.parse CCSAXParser.js:62
cc.FileUtils.cc.Class.extend.dictionaryWithContentsOfFileThreadSafe CCFileUtils.js:612
cc.SpriteFrameCache.cc.Class.extend.addSpriteFrames CCSpriteFrameCache.js:190
cc.Scene.extend.onEnter WelcomeLayer.js:52
(anonymous function) CCClass.js:136
cc.Director.cc.Class.extend.setNextScene CCDirector.js:743
cc.Director.cc.Class.extend.drawScene CCDirector.js:348
cc.DisplayLinkDirector.cc.Director.extend.mainLoop CCDirector.js:1235
callback
```

The same error shows up with MoonWarriors (the other game of the bundle)

Could you tell me what could be the problem? I am using Chrome (32.0.1700.107 m) and IIS as a web server

Comment: this is for cocos2d-x, right? Just asking because of the tags (I changed cocos2d-iphone to cocos2d-x).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forget add s_runnerplist to array of g_resources

```
var g_resources = [
//image
s_HelloBG,
s_start_n,
s_start_s,
s_PlayBG,
s_runner,
s_runnerplist
];
```